# Master Page label visibility in child page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make a label invisible in child page which is defined in master page.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((Label)Master.FindControl("mylbl")).Visible = false;
```

put this in page load of the child page , `mylbl` refers to the ID of the label

it might be `Master.Page.FindControl ....` now that I think of it, it's been a while , but that's how you do it

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this will cause a permissions error. Something like "The object is not a friend of blah blah blah . . ." Let me know if I am mistaken because I am fighting with something similar and this could help.

Comment: javascript and jquery are definetly good options as well and very easy to do , but it is definetly possible in code-behind.  A label is a control , you might get better google results on master page control rather then label

Comment: This worked.((HyperLink)Master.FindControl("login")).Visible = false;

Comment: @TwinklingStar Just a forewarning: Setting the visibility of an asp.net server-side control will cause it not to be rendered at all. Other scripts and/or variable references may either be thrown off or generate an object reference error if the control is not rendered. To fix this, use my suggestion below and set the CSS 'display' value to 'none' instead of setting its visibility property.

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript. Normally in this situation, you would reference your label using 
(assuming your label's ID is my_label_id)

```
document.GetElementById('<%= my_label_id.ClientId %>')
```

. . . or if you are using jquery . . .

```
$('#<%= my_label_id.ClientId %>')
```

However, AFAIK you cannot use clientid to reference a server-side control located on the master page from a content page. So I would either give the control a unique class name using the asp.net label attribute `CssClass="myLabelClass"` or retrieve the client Id by building the page, viewing the source, and finding the client ID. Steps for this can be found here:
[How to use javascript in content page, asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056777/how-to-use-javascript-in-content-page-asp-net/14057093#14057093)

Once you correctly reference the item, simply change the "display" style attribute to "none" as seen below. 
Using jQuery and assuming your CssClass name is *myLabelClass*:

```
$('.myLabelClass').css('display','none');
```

If you wanted this to occur on page load you could do the following:

```
$(function(){
    $('.myLabelClass').css('display','none');
});
```